# Add a button with elseif $row?

Tags: php, button

I need to place a button that says "Yes", but I need that when clicking on the button take the user to a web page, here is the php code for them to review:

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="member">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10">Players Not Activated</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td class="on">#</td>
            <td class="on">ID</td>
            <td class="on">Username</td>
            <td class="on">Email</td>
            <td class="on">Tribe</td>
            <td class="on">Activation Code</td>
            <td class="on">Act 2??</td>
            <td class="on">Time</td>
            <td class="on">PLAY</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".TB_PREFIX."activate";
            $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], $sql);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $i++;
                if($row['tribe'] == 1) {$tribe = "Roman"; }
                elseif($row['tribe'] == 2) {$tribe = "Teuton"; }
                elseif($row['tribe'] == 3) {$tribe = "Gaul"; }

                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$i."</td>
                    <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['username']."</td>
                    <td><a href=\"mailto:".$row['email']."\">".$row['email']."</a></td>
                    <td>".$tribe."</td>
                    <td>".$row['act']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['act2']."</td>
                    <td class=\"hab\">".date('d:m:Y H:i', $row['timestamp'])."</td>

                </tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need the button to appear where it says "PLAY"

and the destination url i want is this link:

```
<a href="activate.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
```

I have tried 4 days ago to be able to make it work but whenever I modify the file I receive a blank error page.

Comment: turn on display_errors in your php.ini

Comment: what script has problems, activate.php? can you show it?

Comment: hi thank for your reply, i think the error is because im not declare the variables or something, im not expert on php but i know the basic, thank you!

Comment: yes i have activate.php page code is this:

Comment: Do you get a white page or a error page, like 400 not found?

Comment: no i dont get error 400 only blank page